# Video recording of the window on OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, video-recording

I am trying to write a program for recording windows, but for some reason, after the program finishes, I get a corrupted `.avi` file.
I don't understand what the problem is. The `hwnd2mat()` and `windowNames()` functions work correctly, the error is clearly not in it. The code looks massive, but in fact, most of the code is occupied by the translation of the image from the HWND to the Mat. Also it should be noted that the resulting image after recording, always has the same size (irrespective of the recording time).

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>

BOOL CALLBACK windowNames(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    const DWORD TITLE_SIZE = 1024;
    WCHAR windowTitle[TITLE_SIZE];

    GetWindowTextW(hwnd, windowTitle, TITLE_SIZE);

    int length = ::GetWindowTextLength(hwnd);
    std::wstring title(&windowTitle[0]);
    if (!IsWindowVisible(hwnd) || length == 0 || title == L"Program Manager") {
        return TRUE;
    }

    // Retrieve the pointer passed into this callback, and re-'type' it.
    // The only way for a C API to pass arbitrary data is by means of a void*.
    std::vector<std::wstring>& titles = *reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::wstring>*>(lParam);
    titles.push_back(title);

    return TRUE;
}

cv::Mat hwnd2mat(HWND hwnd)
{
    HDC hwindowDC, hwindowCompatibleDC;

    int height, width, srcheight, srcwidth;
    HBITMAP hbwindow;
    cv::Mat src;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER  bi;
    HBITMAP bi2;
    hwindowDC = GetDC(hwnd);
    hwindowCompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hwindowDC);
    SetStretchBltMode(hwindowCompatibleDC, COLORONCOLOR);

    RECT windowsize;    // get the height and width of the screen
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &windowsize);

    srcheight = windowsize.bottom;
    srcwidth = windowsize.right;
    height = windowsize.bottom / 1;  //change this to whatever size you want to resize to
    width = windowsize.right / 1;

    // create a bitmap
    hbwindow = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hwindowDC, width, height);
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);    //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/window/dd183402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    bi.biWidth = width;
    bi.biHeight = -height;  //this is the line that makes it draw upside down or not
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 1;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 2;
    bi.biClrUsed = 3;
    bi.biClrImportant = 4;

    // use the previously created device context with the bitmap
    SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow);
    // copy from the window device context to the bitmap device context
    StretchBlt(hwindowCompatibleDC, 0, 0, width, height, hwindowDC, 0, 0, srcwidth, srcheight, SRCCOPY); //change SRCCOPY to NOTSRCCOPY for wacky colors !

    src.create(height, width, CV_8UC4);
    GetDIBits(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow, 0, height, src.data, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);  //copy from hwindowCompatibleDC to hbwindow

    // avoid memory leak
    DeleteObject(hbwindow);
    DeleteDC(hwindowCompatibleDC);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwindowDC);

    return src;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> titles; // we use std::wstring in place of std::string. This is necessary so that the entire character set can be represented.
    EnumWindows(windowNames, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&titles));
    HWND hwndDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
    size_t number = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (const auto& title : titles)
        std::wcout << L"Title: " << i++ << title << std::endl;
    std::cin >> number;
    HWND hwndWindow = FindWindow(NULL, titles[number].c_str());
    cv::namedWindow("output", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cv::Mat src = hwnd2mat(/*hwndDesktop*/hwndWindow);
    cv::VideoWriter outputVideo("output.avi", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 1, cv::Size(src.cols, src.rows));
    outputVideo.write(src);
    int key = 0;
    while (key != 27)
    {
         src = hwnd2mat(hwndWindow);
         outputVideo.write(src);
        cv::imshow("output", src);
        key = cv::waitKey(60); //press ESC to end
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've never heard of *OpenSv*. Is it typeo?

Comment: Recording the screen with GDI will get you nowhere in terms of speed and compression. You need hardware accelerated screen capturing. Check my library : https://github.com/WindowsNT/ScreenCapture

Comment: @KaiserKatze, my mistake. Topic has the correct title.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Thanks, but I am trying to implement a recording using OpenCV.

Comment: @SkivHisink it will  not work.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Why? If we can capture an image and burn it to a certain frequency, that is why it will not work?

Comment: @SkivHisink GDI is long obsolete in Windows, especially for things that you need speed.It wouldn't capture alpha in colors also.  Compressing with MJGP will use the CPU which is nowadays also obsolete since you can use Media Foundation to compress in GPU in H264/H265. indows already provides new libraries to do that, why using OpenCV anyway, we are not in Windows 95.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis if you want to be constructive, you could have mentioned specific APIs such as the ["desktop duplication" API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/desktop-dup-api) and DirectShow/MSMF and [ffmpeg's libav* APIs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20libav*). no need to be derisive.

Comment: Re the MJPG codec, did you try it with other codecs e.g. XVID? Also does MJPG codec is proven to work on your system with OCV in other use cases? Does OCV saves correctly as mjpg video a single loaded or drawn image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that we need to transfer the Mat from BGRA to BGR during the transfer of the frame to the `VideoWriter` object.
For correct operation, it is necessary to write

`Mat bgrImg; cvtColor(src, bgrImg, COLOR_BGRA2BGR);`

in the range before sending a frame and send `bgrImg` as a frame.

Comment: source: https://forum.opencv.org/t/video-recording-of-the-window-on-opencv-c/647/2

Answer (score 0):

`VideoWriter` instances need to be closed using the `release()` method. that finalizes the video container file.

Comment: Added this method but it didn't help.

Comment: https://github.com/SkivHisink/MultiThreadingRecording/blob/master/MultiThreadingRecording/main.cpp in the end of main()

Comment: how big does the file get? check `outputVideo.isOpened()`

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV has no support for modern screen capture AFAIK. You’ll need to use platform-specific means of doing this (maybe encapsulated in some library). The problem here is that the screen data is already in the GPU, and by using OpenCV you’re forcing it to be copied to the main memory and processed with a relatively slow CPU. It won’t perform well. Instead, a platform-specific approach will process the data on the GPU, using it to both extract the window’s frames and encode them. It’ll be very efficient both in terms of speed as well as energy consumption (you’ll vastly improve battery life while the capture is running, and will prevent the fans from being annoying on notebooks).

Comment: that's not the issue here. the issue is the empty .avi file.